# Spring Boot does not recognize MongoDB RestController class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to MongoDB and I am trying to use it with my SpringBoot application. I have followed my tutorials online and have downloaded their code and got it execute.

However for whatever reason my project fails to be able to print out
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped “{[/findAllBooks/{id}],methods=[GET]}”

I was wondering if anyone would be able to advise me if it is due to the nature of my project structure .
I wasn’t sure if my SpringBootMain could see my  Controller class.

My project structure is best viewed here
https://github.com/emuldrew855/backend/tree/A/B-Testing/src/main/java/com/ebay/queens/demo

My Controller class

```
package com.ebay.queens.demo.resource;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v2")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/AddUser")
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Added user with id: " + user.getId();
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User> getAll(){
        List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

My main class

```
package com.ebay.queens.demo;
    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SpringBootMain implements CommandLineRunner {
        @Autowired
        private TokenUtilityClass tokenUtilityClass;

    @Bean ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {
    return new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(Version1Api.class, Login.class, SignUp.class, Paypal.class); }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // test.authenticationToken();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMain.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: so to be clear it fails in your getAll method?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out why is not working... You are using 2 different WebService API which are incompatible...

Spring-Boot has native API to work with API Rest with `@RestController` annotation. You don't need to use `Glassfish` server.

### Solution #1

1. From `SpringBootMain` remove `@Bean ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {...}`. Now, you API `/v2` will work as expected.
2. Your API `/v1` won't work because it uses other library. You need to change `@Path` to `@GetMapping` or `@PostMapping` and add `@RestController` into your `Version1Api` class.

### Solution #2

You ignore Spring-Boot native Rest API and implement `Glassfish` Server.

1. Add `UserController.class` reference

> @Bean ResourceConfig resourceConfig() {
>       return new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(Version1Api.class, Login.class, SignUp.class, Paypal.class, **UserController.class**); }

2. For `UserController` change `@RestController` to `@Path("/v2")`

---

```
@Path("/v2")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @POST
    @Path("/AddUser")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "Added user with id: " + user.getId();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<User> getAll(){
        List<User> users = this.userRepository.findAll();
        return users;
    }
}
```

Now both API will work as expected

Comment: So i deleted my answer. and voted this up. You are right about the mixing